# C++ displaying directory content issue

Tags: c++, linux, dirent.h

Firstly, Sorry for the bad title that I've named.

This is the question that I just asked:

[Display files contain inside a particular directory by using C++ in LINUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684295/display-files-contain-inside-a-particular-directory-by-using-c-in-linux)

This is the source that I refer to:

[Reading The Contents of Directories](http://www.cpp-home.com/tutorials/107_6.htm)

This [THREAD (C Programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707050/displaying-files-from-directory) having the same output like mine.

FileSystem Folder Contents

```
- test.txt
- abc.txt
- item.txt
- records.txt
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Dir* dir = opendir("/home/user/desktop/TEST/FileSystem");
    struct dirent* entry;

    cout<<"Directory Contents: "<<endl;
    while((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        cout << "%s " << entry->d_name << endl;
    }    
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Directory Contents:

%s ..
%s item.txt
%s test.txt
%s records.txt
%s .
%s abc.txt
```

My main question is why it will display the ".." and "." on the OUTPUT. Why it will be there, is there any special meaning/purposes? How do I get rid of that and just display files **ONLY** in the folder?

Thank you in advance to you guys on answering my question. I hope you guys don't mind I ask a lot of question.

Comment: `.` - current directory, `..` - parental directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix and Windows, all directories always contain the two entries `"."` (the directory itself) and `".."` it's parent (or itself, in the rare cases where it has no parent).  Under Unix, the usual convention is that directories whose name starts with a `'.'` are "hidden", and will not be displayed, but this is up to the displaying program; when you read a directory, you still see them.  If you want to follow this convention, a simple `if` in your loop is all you need:

```
dirent* entry = readdir( dir );
while ( entry != nullptr ) {
    if ( entry->d_name[0] != '.' ) {
        std::cout << entry->d_name << std::endl;
    }
    entry = readdir( dir );
}
```